# How to treat a phrase containing stopwords as a single token with Python nltk.tokenize

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, stop-words

A string can be tokenized by removing some unnecessary stopwords using [nltk.tokenize](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html). But how can I tokenize a phrase containing stopwords as a single token, while removing other stopwords?

For example:

Input: Trump is the President of the United States.

Output: ['Trump','President of the United States']

How can I get the result that just removes 'is' and first 'the' but doesn't remove 'of' and second 'the'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nltk's [Multi-Word Expression Tokenizer](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.mwe) which allows to merge multi-word expressions into single tokens. You can create a lexicon of multi-word expressions and add entries to it like this:

```
from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer
mwetokenizer = MWETokenizer([('President','of','the','United','States')], separator=' ')
mwetokenizer.add_mwe(('President','of','France'))
```

Note that MWETokenizer takes a list of tokenized text as input, and re-tokenizes it. So, first tokenize the sentence eg. with `word_tokenize()`, and then feed it into the MWETokenizer:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
sentence = "Trump is the President of the United States, and Macron is the President of France."
mwetokenized_sentence = mwetokenizer.tokenize(word_tokenize(sentence))
# ['Trump', 'is', 'the', 'President of the United States', ',', 'and', 'Macron', 'is', 'the', 'President of France', '.']
```

Then, filter out stop-words to get the final filtered tokenized sentence:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
filtered_sentence = [token for token in mwetokenizer.tokenize(word_tokenize(sentence)) if token not in stop_words]
print(filtered_sentence)
```

Output:

```
['Trump', 'President of the United States', ',', 'Macron', 'President of France', '.']
```